# java version and PATH on OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation

I'm not sure why my PATH is not being respected regarding where to find java on my MAC OS X 10.9.5.

After searching around I found that the Java version referenced from the command line was at /usr/bin/java, while the Java version referenced by Oracle's tools used by browsers and visible at System Preferences > Java, Open the Java Control Panel, click on Java tab at top, click on View... button, check both User and System tabs for Path, showing in both:
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

The command line picks up 1.6.0_65 even though that is for the version at /usr/bin rather than the one at /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin earlier in the path.

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ josephmurray$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ josephmurray$ which java
/usr/bin/java
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ josephmurray$ echo $PATH
/Applications/tr-sub.app/Contents/MacOS:/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:~/civix:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ josephmurray$ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ josephmurray$ /usr/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~
```

This is preventing me from installing eclipse because it needs Java to be at least 1.7. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be using a backslash to escape the space in the path. While using it is necessary when entering a command on the commandline, it should not be included when setting PATH in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:~/civix:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin"

export PATH=/Applications/tr-sub.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/
```

NB: Each time you edit ~/.bash_profile you need to refresh the environment variables in the shell by running:
$ source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with Eclipse, you need to install a full JDK, not use a JRE. The installed JRE is lacking debug symbols etc.

You can install it from [Oracle's Java SE Development Kit download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

You will then also be able to use command line tools such as javac.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using it for PHP and python development, not java.